# C++ Boost library geometry.hpp

Tags: c++, boost, ubuntu-12.04, boost-geometry

I installed boost library in my ubuntu 12.04 LTS using command libboost-all-dev, but when I include /boost/geometry.hpp it doesn't get included. I have checked the system and it doesn't contain any geometry.hpp file or even any geometry. There is no geometry file in the boost library that i downloaded

Comment: maybe you can try `find /usr/ -name 'geometry.hpp'` to check whether this file is on your disk

Answer (score 2):

I downloaded boost 1.54 from http://www.boost.org/users/download/ 2 days ago. The version I got has

boost_1_54_0/boost/geometry.hpp

and

boost_1_54_0/boost/geometry/geometry.hpp

how did you get boost?

Answer (score 2):

Poking around a bit, downloading boost from the command line (apt-get or whatever) gets you boost version 1.46, but the geometry library only came out with boost 1.47.
You're better off getting boost from http://www.boost.org/users/download/ because ubuntu's repositories are always (in my expericence) several versions behind the most recent.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before you may download the most recent version of Boost from here: http://www.boost.org/users/download/

Then to install it follow this guide: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#id25

In short:

```
$ ./bootstrap.sh
```

then

```
$ ./b2 install
```

This will build all libraries (that are required to be built) and copy headers and libs into the /usr directory. So you should probably put `sudo` before `./b2`. Then you'll be able to use them without passing additional parameters into the compiler.

It's also possible to build only some of the libaries. Check the guide.